# Material UI Alerts using custom colors

Tags: material-ui

Can I set a custom color for a MUI Alert component? The [docs suggest](https://material-ui.com/components/alert/#color) that the only color options are the four that match the four severity props.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible. Quoting the [API docs](https://material-ui.com/api/alert/):

> You can override the style of the component thanks to one of these
> customization points:
>
> - With a rule name of the classes object prop.
> - With a global class name.
> - With a theme and an overrides property.

A crude example in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-66000868-5ixnz?file=/index.js)

Answer (score 5):

For MUI V5 in case someone is looking to change the background color in the theme this worked for me.

```
export const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiAlert: {
      styleOverrides: {
        standardSuccess: {
          backgroundColor: 'green',
          color: 'white'
        },
        standardError: {
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          color: 'white'
        },
        standardWarning: {
          backgroundColor: 'orange',
          color: 'white'
        },
        standardInfo: {
          backgroundColor: 'grey',
          color: 'black'
        }
      }
    },
    
  },
});
```

And is working by setting the variant:

```
<Alert severity="success">Success</Alert>
<Alert severity="error">Error</Alert>
<Alert severity="warning">Warning</Alert>
<Alert severity="info">Info</Alert>
```

Answer (score 2):

**A simple approach would be:**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  myAlert: {
    color: "#ffffff",
    backgroundColor: "#000000"
  }
});

function MyCustomAlert() {
    const classes = useStyles();

    return (
        <Alert severity="error" className={classes.myAlert}>
            <AlertTitle>Error</AlertTitle>
            {"I am an error message !"}
        </Alert>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess another option, if you don't wanna deal with css classes, could be:

(using **mui v5** and **typescript**)

first u define your styled component:

```
interface IAlert extends AlertProps {
      background?: string
}
    
export const Alert = styled(MUIAlert)<IAlert>(({ background }) => ({
    background,
}))
```

then, on your component that uses the Alert:

```
const Component = ({type}) => {
  ...
  const CUSTOM_COLORS_MAPPING = {
    success: palette.success[500],
    info: palette.secondary[500],
    error: palette.error[500],
    warning: palette.warning[500],
  }

  return (
    ...
    <Alert severity={type} background={CUSTOM_COLORS_MAPPING[type]}>
      {message}
    </Alert>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one more way in which I've used it in my mui v5 react app using styled api

1. Creating custom style component using styled api

```
const StyledAlert = styled(Alert)(({ theme }) => ({
 backgroundColor: '#fde8e9', // your custom color
}));
```

2. Simply use the styled version in your code

```
<StyledAlert
 severity="success"
 variant="filled"
 >
 This is a success alert — check it out!
 </StyledAlert>
```